Compositor in Viewport : footage and render misalignment
I'm trying to add elements to a footage. To be able to align the elements in real-time, I'm using the viewport option Compositor > Camera. My issue is that the footage and the render don't align most of the time. In camera view, as soon as I move the view or zoom, what is aligned in the compositor is misaligned in the viewport. I've tried every settings of the Scale node with no success.
Here is my compositing nodes :

So I'm compositing together :

A HD footage (1920x1080)
My scene
A mask to define what part should be replaced

With trial-and-error, I've come to the conclusion I need a Scale node for both the footage and the mask. But I'm unable to find a setting that works in the compositor and the viewport.
Here is an example of how the elements are misaligned, in the viewport (camera view) :

As you see here, the yellow circle (a lamp gizmo) should stay at the same place in the render but it doesn't. To summarize the issue, here are the different possible settings for the Scale node of the compositor when panning or zooming in the camera view :
No scale node

Scale : stretch

Scale : fit

Scale : crop

What settings should I use, so that the footage follows correctly the camera view in the viewport, and stays aligned also with the mask ?
The solution may be super simple, but that's the first time I'm really using the compositor in the viewport.

what version of blender are you using?
I had a similar issue compositing real footage with cg.
in my case, i think the issue was only with the real-time compositing, and when rendered, everything scaled and moved correctly. I think the realtime part was fixed for me in blender 4.1 or 4.2.

@JohnCheathem I'm on Blender 4.2.0. Everything works fine for me when rendered, it's really about having the same result in the viewport in camera view.

ah i see, i ended up putting an emmisive plane in the background alligned to the camera view perspective and size, and had the video on that for real-time previewing. kinda hacky.

@JohnCheathem Good idea ! Not perfect but works. Thank you

Happy to help! i think there is a free add on for blender to auto create planes perfectly alligned with the camera at any distance. might be helpful.
